# Service Worker OneSignal conflict React PWA

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, onesignal

I build a PWA with React (CRA) and I'm having problems with Service Worker from OneSignal.
My OneSignalSDKWorker:

```
importScripts('https://pwa.yeapps.com.br/service-worker-custom.js');//My custom service worker
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDKWorker.js');
```

My OneSignalSDK:

```
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js');
```

My index.html:

```
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('OneSignalSDKWorker.js').then(function (registration) {
                console.log('Worker registration successful', registration.scope);                    
            }, function (err) {
                console.log('Worker registration failed', err);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Service Worker is not supported by browser.');
    }
```

But I got an error, when build the app and upload the files:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 error.

Try putting The scripts on the public folder instead of src. Then check if it is loading The correct url.

Comment: But the script are in the public folder

Comment: your error message says you don't. try to open the link of the 3th error (the 404 one). then try to fix this link